# Check underlaying element of position absolute

Tags: javascript, css, html

Im trying to simulate mouse movement for a chromecast project. A position absolute element is moving around the screen with the WSAD keys. Now I am trying to get the underlaying element. But when i do this i get the full DOM instead of just the element thats under this 'mouse' element.

I've created a JSFiddle to show you what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/fu5drfud/1/ (You can move the 'mouse ' with WSAD and you can see in your console which element it is touching.)

I use the following method for checking the underlaying element:

```
document.elementFromPoint(mouse.left, mouse.top);
```

How can i get the underlaying element?

Comment: try `console.log(event.target)`

Comment: @salniro It's not an event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get text behind an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435888/get-text-behind-an-element)

Comment: @MelanciaUK Sadly it isn't.

Comment: Wouldn't the new feature element**s**fromPoint be what your searching for? Its still not implemented in most browsers: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementsfrompoint